# Is there a way to transfer a boarding pass from Gmail to Wallet on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gmail, wallet

- iOS 10
- iPhone 5
- Airline: Westjet.
- Email App:  Gmail

I do not want to download an app every time I get a new pass.  How can I do this from GMail, rather than adding YAA?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's up to the airline to handle that. If there is a pass available for you Wallet, there will be an icon on the website where you can print the pass that says **Add to Apple Wallet/Passbook**

If not, you may have to download the airline's app. Even then, there's still the chance that there won't be a mobile boarding pass.

I know that with Southwest Airlines, you can only get a mobile boarding pass through their app, and only if it is a single ticket trip (i.e. no other people flying on the same purchase).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.pkpass` file in an app that doesn’t directly support adding the pass to Apple Wallet (e.g. attached to an email viewed in Gmail, downloaded to Files from Chrome, etc), you can **send it to yourself via iMessage**, as the Messages app is able to add passes to your Apple Wallet:

- Open the share sheet for the file
- Select “Messages” (select the app itself, not a particular contact). If you don’t see it, try scrolling the list of apps to the right, or pressing the “more” button.
- Enter *your own Apple ID email* as the recipient (if you have a contact set up for yourself, you can also use that).
- Send the message, then open Messages to view it
- Tap the “add” button on the pass